# Use resource file for meta content in HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have multilanguage website and, deppending of languane, keywords should be on that language. Right now it's on English, so in my _Layout.cshtml I have meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="GDPR, privacy, pact, privacy pact>
```

How to, for example set it to Russian from Resource file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the programming languages you are using. You could use AJAX/JS, PHP, or pretty much any other server-side language. You just include an if statement to see what language you need the metadata for, and then use AJAX or a server-side language to get the right data from the separate file. If you tell me what programming languages you are using I could try to code it out.